# Rate-limit exceeded That’s all we know, Error 403, yt3.ggpht.com

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I grab data from youtube data api,

```
image: {
bannerImageUrl: "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-HzM7tqQ-Lbo/V-tnNJuy7JI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/Yb5Fnx29BvcWYYAQ9ReVeKlY8DaSuS8agCL8B/w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/Channel-Art-Template-%2528Photoshop%2529.png",
...
}
```

as for image banner of the channel, I directly use it in `<img>` tag.

since I am in development (alot of refresh page happening), then this error kick,

```
403. That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL /-HzM7tqQ-Lbo/V-tnNJuy7JI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/Yb5Fnx29BvcWYYAQ9ReVeKlY8DaSuS8agCL8B/w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/Channel-Art-Template-%2528Photoshop%2529.png from this server. (Client IP address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Rate-limit exceeded That’s all we know.
```

So my question is, am I allowed to directly use the image from `yt3.ggpht.com` and show it in my webpage ?

I search around mention that bandwidth limit, any solution for this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based from [Google's  Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors),

> Error code 403 `rateLimitExceeded`, indicates that the global or overall project rate limits have been exceeded. Recommended action for this is to retry using [exponential back-off](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#backoff). You need to slow down the rate at which you are sending the requests.

And with regards to using images from YouTube in your website, I suggest that you please check YouTube's [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=CA&template=terms) especially permissions and restrictions on the use of content.

You may also check given workaround in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/VIW7Gk8Deeg). Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't think the problem is that. This is not a quota issue of an API key. It's something different. @patrickDkoe is just using the URL he previously got through the API to render an `img`. It's a call from the user client, like it happens on YouTube (except for things like HTTP referrer).